# Is it possible to join 2 views with duplicated data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a dummy data warehouse and trying to join 2 separate views, each view works fine on its own. However, when combined there appears to be something in my group by statement which is causing the data to be incorrect.

```
create view CentreSizing as
select CentreID, Name,
case
  when Capacity between 0 and 199 then 'Small'
  when Capacity between 200 and 900 then 'Medium'
  else 'Large'
end as Size
from Centre;

create view sizeQuantities as
select cs.Size, count(*) as "Occurences" from
CentreSizing cs
group by cs.Size;

create view AvgSpendings2018 as
select cs.Size, monthname(d.DateStamp) as "Month", sum(e.Cost)/quant.Occurences as 
"AverageExpense"
from Expense e join CentreSizing cs on e.CentreID = cs.CentreID
join DateTime d on e.DateTimeID = d.DateTimeID
join sizeQuantities quant on quant.Size = cs.Size
where YEAR(d.DateStamp) = 2018
group by cs.Size, MONTH(d.DateStamp);

create view TotalSpendings2018 as
select e.CentreID, c.Name, cs.Size , monthname(d.DateStamp) as "Month", sum(e.Cost) as 
"TotalExpense" from Expense e
 left join DateTime d on e.DateTimeID = d.DateTimeID
 join Centre c on c.CentreID = e.CentreID
join CentreSizing cs on c.CentreID = cs.CentreID
where year(d.DateStamp) = 2018
group by month(d.DateStamp), e.CentreID;
```

All of the view creations work as expected on their own, however when I attempt to combine the results to show the total expenses per month, in comparison to the average for centre's of similar size, the results are not as expected.

```
select ts.CentreID, ts.Name, ts.Size, ts.Month, avg.AverageExpense
from TotalSpendings2018 ts join AvgSpendings2018 avg on
ts.Size = avg.Size
Group by ts.CentreID, ts.Size, ts.Month;

| CentreID | Name                               | Size   | Month     | AverageExpense 
|
+----------+-------------------------------------+--------+-----------+---------------- 
+
|        1 | Queen Alexandra Hospital           | Large  | April     |      1490.0000 
|
|        1 | Queen Alexandra Hospital           | Large  | August    |      1490.0000 
|
|        1 | Queen Alexandra Hospital           | Large  | December  |      1490.0000 
|
|        1 | Queen Alexandra Hospital           | Large  | February  |      1490.0000 
|
|        1 | Queen Alexandra Hospital           | Large  | January   |      1490.0000 
|
|        1 | Queen Alexandra Hospital           | Large  | July      |      1490.0000 
|
|        1 | Queen Alexandra Hospital           | Large  | June      |      1490.0000 
|
|        1 | Queen Alexandra Hospital           | Large  | March     |      1490.0000 
|
|        1 | Queen Alexandra Hospital           | Large  | May       |      1490.0000 
|
|        1 | Queen Alexandra Hospital           | Large  | November  |      1490.0000 
|
|        1 | Queen Alexandra Hospital           | Large  | October   |      1490.0000 
|
|        1 | Queen Alexandra Hospital           | Large  | September |      1490.0000 
|
|        2 | Southampton General Hospital       | Large  | April     |      1490.0000 
|
|        2 | Southampton General Hospital       | Large  | August    |      1490.0000 
|
|        2 | Southampton General Hospital       | Large  | December  |      1490.0000 
|
|        2 | Southampton General Hospital       | Large  | February  |      1490.0000 
|
|        2 | Southampton General Hospital       | Large  | January   |      1490.0000 
|
|        2 | Southampton General Hospital       | Large  | July      |      1490.0000 
|
|        2 | Southampton General Hospital       | Large  | June      |      1490.0000 
|
|        2 | Southampton General Hospital       | Large  | March     |      1490.0000 
|
|        2 | Southampton General Hospital       | Large  | May       |      1490.0000 
|
|        2 | Southampton General Hospital       | Large  | November  |      1490.0000 
|
|        2 | Southampton General Hospital       | Large  | October   |      1490.0000 
|
|        2 | Southampton General Hospital       | Large  | September |      1490.0000 
|
|        3 | St Richard's Hospital              | Medium | April     |       445.0000 
|
|        3 | St Richard's Hospital              | Medium | August    |       445.0000 
|
|        3 | St Richard's Hospital              | Medium | December  |       445.0000 
|
```

Comment: First thing I notice is your group by in your last view doesn't include all the non-aggregated columns in the select. MySQL will happily run that query, which drives me crazy.

Comment: To my way of thinking, VIEWs serve no purpose in MySQL

Comment: Use a proper `GROUP BY`.  Change the `GROUP BY` of your last query to `group by c.Name, cs.Size ,month(d.DateStamp), e.CentreID`.  Other dbms will not even run your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View TotalSpendings2018 is missing c.Name in the GROUP BY clause (if there is a unique Name for each Center, that should be fine however). While, unlike most other RDBMS, mysql allows this, this is error-prone and not good coding practice.

Regarding the query :

- it actually looks to me like you don’t need a GROUP BY, as there is no aggregation function being used (else : ts.Name and avg.AverageExpense are missing in the GROUP BY)
- from the description of the views I would also guess that you are missing a join condition on "Month", as this column is available in both views
- why are you not displaying the TotalExpense in the output ? I would have thought that’s what you were looking to do (otherwise, you don’t need to join)

My (hopefully educated) guess at your query :

```
select 
    ts.CentreID,
    ts.Name, 
    ts.Size, 
    ts.Month, 
    avg.AverageExpense,
    ts.TotalExpense
from
    TotalSpendings2018 ts 
    join AvgSpendings2018 avg 
    on ts.Size = avg.Size
    and ts.Month = avg.Month
```

Comment: Solved, thanks a bunch. Seems really obvious looking back at it!

Comment: Welcome @DanLincoln !